# How to print regexp matches using awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Is there a way to print a regexp match (but only the matching string) using `awk` command in shell?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, in `awk` use the `match()` function and give it the optional array parameter (`a` in my example). When you do this, the 0-th element will be the part that matched the regex

```
$ echo "blah foo123bar blah" | awk '{match($2,"[a-z]+[0-9]+",a)}END{print a[0]}'
foo123
```

Comment: I know grep -o, it has to be in AWK :)

Comment: I get the error: awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
  >>> {match($2,"[a-z]+[0-9]+", <<<
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

with both zsh and bash

Comment: oh, it's gawk... from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536018/how-to-get-match-regex-pattern-using-awk-from-file "the awk match() function with three arguments only exists in gawk"

Comment: So in other words, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: For those interested in using this gawk-specific match function, it looks like the 3-arg version of match wasn't added to gawk until 3.1: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Feature-History.html

Sadly, the latest Git Bash's environment is using 3.0.4.

Comment: gawk not installed by default in MacOS. Refer to the solution below for wider compatibility implementation using standard awk

Answer (score 27):

An `awk` specific (as opposed to one using `gawk`) implementation of the solution:

```
$ echo "blah foo123bar blah" | awk 'match($0,/[a-z]+[0-9]+/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
foo123
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this construct quite a bit:

```
split(substr($0, match($0, /[0-9]+ [Bb]ytes/)), a, " ");
print a[1];
```