# How to print matched regex pattern using awk?

Tags: regex, awk

Using `awk`, I need to find a word in a file that matches a regex pattern.

I *only* want to print the word matched with the pattern.

So if in the line, I have:

```
xxx yyy zzz
```

And pattern:

```
/yyy/
```

I want to only get:

```
yyy
```

---

EDIT:
thanks to **kurumi** i managed to write something like this:

```
awk '{
        for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
                tmp=match($i, /[0-9]..?.?[^A-Za-z0-9]/)
                if(tmp) {
                        print $i
                }
        }
}' $1
```

and this is what i needed :) thanks a lot!

Comment: @maxtaldykin Could you move your self-answer from the question into separate answer please?

Comment: You don't need to do `tmp=match($i, /regexp);if(tmp){}`, you should just be able to do `if(tmp ~ $i){}` because `~` means "matches the regexp".

Answer (score 197, accepted):

This is the very basic

```
awk '/pattern/{ print $0 }' file
```

ask `awk` to search for `pattern` using `//`, then print out the line, which by default is called a record, denoted by $0. At least read up the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual).

If you only want to get print out the matched word.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i=="yyy"){print $i} } }' file
```

Comment: Since `print` is the default action: `awk '/pattern/' file` will suffice.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, yes I do know this fact. To a beginner like marverix, its meant to be more visual.

Comment: I don't doubt your knowledge. The information may be useful to others finding this answer, however.

Comment: N.B: @marverix will have to a little more homework to get the `for`-loop to work if (a) "yyy" is a regular expression and not a straight string and (b) if that "yyy" does not match an entire field within a record.

Comment: @Johnsyweb  what if "yyy" does not match an entire field within a record... get stuck here...

Comment: @lorniper I think [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5536342/78845) copes with that.

Comment: It wouldn't be `$i=="yyy"`; it would be `$i ~ /yyy/` for a regular expression.

Comment: Wow, what a horrible tool and language! "do one thing and do it well" doesn't apply to awk.

Answer (score 173):

It sounds like you are trying to emulate GNU's `grep -o` behaviour. This will do that providing you only want the first match on each line:

```
awk 'match($0, /regex/) {
    print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
}
' file
```

Here's an example, using GNU's `awk` implementation ([gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk)):

```
awk 'match($0, /a.t/) {
    print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
}
' /usr/share/dict/words | head
act
act
act
act
aft
ant
apt
art
art
art
```

Read about [`match`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-match_0028_0029-function), [`substr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-substr_0028_0029-function), [`RSTART`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#index-RSTART-variable) and [`RLENGTH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#index-RLENGTH-variable) in the `awk` manual.

After that you may wish to extend this to deal with multiple matches on the same line.

Comment: N.B: To answer that last part, all of the constructs needed are in  [kurumi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536018/how-to-get-match-regex-pattern-using-awk-from-file/5536068#5536068) and my own.

Comment: Great answer. Just I would like an explanation here in place because I am lazy. But that's why I am using AWK!

Comment: What if i want to do something with the match result except of print it? For example, i want to add all the matches into array.

Comment: @evya2005: You could simply replace the call Ron print with the assignment you need.

Comment: it's not working for me. only print work. can you show me example?

Comment: @Johnsyweb also, if there is more then one match on the same line it will return only the first match in the line and ignore the rest. do you know how to solve this?

Comment: To access all matches on one line, I'd use a `for`-loop like in [kurumi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5536068/78845). "it's not working for me. " is beginning to sound like a new question, rather than a comment on an answer to an existing question.

Comment: Why the `%` instead of a `$` as your prompt string? That's **awk**ward. Seriously though, I'm half-tempted to edit your answer and change it so people don't get so confused. I just copy-pasted it when trying to run your example and got `%: command not found`.

Comment: I made the change. Super minor. I hope you don't mind. Also, very nice answer. I couldn't find an `awk`-compatible (instead of using `gawk` extensions) example this clear anywhere else. Thank you. This appears to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @GabrielStaples: Nice edits, thanks. The `%` is the default `PS1` prompt in [tag:zsh] (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/362773/2818#comment643265_362773).

Answer (score 51):

***gawk*** can get the matching part of every line using this as action:

```
{ if (match($0,/your regexp/,m)) print m[0] }
```

> match(string, regexp [, array])
>   If array is present, it is cleared,
>   and then the zeroth element of array is set to the entire portion of
>   string matched by regexp. If regexp contains parentheses, the
>   integer-indexed elements of array are set to contain the portion of
>   string matching the corresponding parenthesized subexpression.
>   http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions

Answer (score 20):

If Perl is an option, you can try this:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /(regex)/' file
```

To implement case-insensitive matching, add the `i` modifier

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /(regex)/i' file
```

To print everything AFTER the match:

```
perl -lne 'if ($found){print} else{if (/regex(.*)/){print $1; $found++}}' textfile
```

To print the match and everything after the match:

```
perl -lne 'if ($found){print} else{if (/(regex.*)/){print $1; $found++}}' textfile
```

Comment: This actually did exactly what I wanted. Was not able to make it work with awk to print my match, but perl did the trick.

Answer (score 18):

If you are only interested in the last line of input and you expect to find only one match (for example a part of the summary line of a shell command), you can also try this very compact code, adopted from [How to print regexp matches using `awk`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466411/print-regexp-matches-in-awk):

```
$ echo "xxx yyy zzz" | awk '{match($0,"yyy",a)}END{print a[0]}'
yyy
```

Or the more complex version with a partial result:

```
$ echo "xxx=a yyy=b zzz=c" | awk '{match($0,"yyy=([^ ]+)",a)}END{print a[1]}'
b
```

Warning: the `awk` `match()` function with three arguments only exists in `gawk`, not in `mawk`

Here is another nice solution using a [lookbehind regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in `grep` instead of `awk`. This solution has lower requirements to your installation:

```
$ echo "xxx=a yyy=b zzz=c" | grep -Po '(?<=yyy=)[^ ]+'
b
```

Comment: Why did you add "tail -n1"? This should work fine without it, no?

Comment: @ArthurAccioly Correct. I used the term to extract the average roundtrip time from a ping call, that's where it came from. funny that it took 4 years to discover it ;)

Answer (score 12):

Off topic, this can be done using the grep also, just posting it here in case if anyone is looking for grep solution

```
echo 'xxx yyy zzze ' | grep -oE 'yyy'
```

Comment: Simple way to grab it even with regex. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This works for me; My case is like: echo "web_port=8080,shutdown_port=8005" | grep -oE "web_port=[0-9]+" # return 8080

Answer (score 5):

Using sed can also be elegant in this situation. Example (replace line with matched group "yyy" from line):

```
$ cat testfile
xxx yyy zzz
yyy xxx zzz
$ cat testfile | sed -r 's#^.*(yyy).*$#\1#g'
yyy
yyy
```

Relevant manual page: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions

Comment: For non-gnu sed the solution is something like this:
`sed -n 's/^.*\(yyy\).*$/\1/gp'  < testfile`

Comment: @GrigoryEntin - bsd sed works fine with the original answer.  The extended regex switch supported by POSIX is -E, but in FreeBSD at least -r is the same as -E (-r added in 2010).  Anyway, try with -E (gnu sed added -E in 4.3)

Answer (score 0):

If you know what column the text/pattern you're looking for (e.g. "yyy") is in, you can just check that specific column to see if it matches, and print it.

For example, given a file with the following contents, (called **asdf.txt**)

```
xxx yyy zzz
```

to only print the second column if it matches the pattern "yyy", you could do something like this:

```sh
awk '$2 ~ /yyy/ {print $2}' asdf.txt
```

Note that this will also match basically any line where the second column has a "yyy" in it, like these:

```
xxx yyyz zzz
xxx zyyyz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "abc123def" | awk '

function MATCH(haystack, needle, ltrim, rtrim)
{
if(ltrim == 0 && !length(ltrim))
  ltrim = 0;

if(rtrim == 0 && !length(rtrim))
  rtrim = 0;

return substr(haystack, match(haystack, needle) + ltrim, RLENGTH - ltrim - rtrim);
}
    
{
print $0 " - " MATCH($0, "123");             # 123
print $0 " - " MATCH($0, "[0-9]*d", 0, 1);   # 123
print $0 " - " MATCH($0, "1234");            # Nothing printed
}'
```