# Awk split string into words and numbers

Tags: awk

I am trying to split of letter and number boundaries, but the solution with lookarounds fails:

```
echo 50cats30dogs100squirrels | awk '{split($0,a,/(?<=\D)(.*)(?=\d)/); print a[1],a[2],a[3]}'

awk: illegal primary in regular expression (?<=\D)(.*)(?=\d) at <=\D)(.*)(?=\d)
 source line number 1
 context is
     >>> {split($0,a,/(?<=\D)(.*)(?=\d)/) <<<
```

Is there a way to do this in Awk in other way?

Edit:

Sorry for not being clear. The expected output is to just add spaces like this:

```
50 cats 30 dogs 100 squirrels
```

Comment: You might have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430502/awk-field-separator-with-regexp-lookahead-or-lookbehind). To summarize, awk doesn't have look-behind regex.

Comment: `awk` doesn't support look arounds, if you could post what is your sample input and sample output in your question then we could get more clear picture on it and could try to help here, thank you.

Comment: What should the array `a` contain after? I can't tell if you want the numbers or the words.

Comment: Regarding your edit: What? `50cats30dogs100squirrels` -> `50 cats 30 dogs 100 squirrels` is in fact `2S5M1I^ATAG1I3M1D5M` -> `SSMMMMMI^^^^IMMMDMMMMM`?

Comment: I was thinking of this to be a toy example (or a step on the way) to tackle a more complex problem. Will post a new question instead.

Comment: @LechKaczmarczyk, sure, you could rollback to your original question please to avoid confusions, cheers.

Comment: Hmm, wasn't there just like yesterday a similar question? The latter kind of transformation, I mean.

Comment: @JamesBrown, from me? I posted on a different forum (https://www.biostars.org/p/494753/), but the context was of the question was broader. The problems are indeed related, though.

Comment: No, someone else asked a similar question (the latter edit) like yesterday or two days ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your shown samples only. Could you please try following, if this is what you are looking for. Written and tested in GNU `awk`(should work in any `awk` I believe).

```
echo "50cats30dogs100squirrels" | awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]+/," & ")} 1'
```

Output will be as follows for shown samples:

```
50 cats 30 dogs 100 squirrels
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to do this in Awk in other way?

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
50cats30dogs100squirrels
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="([[:alpha:]]+)|([[:digit:]]+)"}{$1=$1;print}' file.txt
```

output

```
50 cats 30 dogs 100 squirrels
```

Explanation: I instruct AWK that column is (one or more letters) or (one or more digits) using `FPAT`. Then I do `$1=$1` to cause string rebuilt (without `$1=$1;` output would be same as input) and `print` it.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: This is interesting! Can it be applied to a specific field only, using a delimiter, or (better) alternatively stored in an array?

Comment: @LechKaczmarczyk it is impossible to use `FS` and `FPAT` together, more precisly *Assigning a value to FPAT overrides field splitting with FS and with FIELDWIDTHS.* https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html You might use `patsplit` function to store extracted elements into array as described in https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

Answer (score 3):

`(?<=\D)(.*)(?=\d)` is a PCRE. No mandatory Unix tools as defined by the POSIX standard support PCREs. awk in particular supports EREs.

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ echo '50cats30dogs100squirrels' | awk -v FPAT='[0-9]+|[^0-9]+' '{$1=$1}1'
50 cats 30 dogs 100 squirrels
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```sh
echo 50cats30dogs100squirrels | awk '{while (match($0, /[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+/)) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH);$0=substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)}}'
```

Which yields:

```sh
50
cats
30
dogs
100
squirrels
```

Answer (score 1):

With gawk, this is a job for `gensub`, and then `split` into an array is easier:

```sh
gawk '
  BEGIN {
    s = "50cats30dogs100squirrels"
    t = gensub(/[[:alpha:]]+|[[:digit:]]+/, "& ", "g", s)
    print ">" t "<"
    split(t, a)
    for (i in a) print i, a[i]
  }
'
```

outputs

```
>50 cats 30 dogs 100 squirrels <
1 50
2 cats
3 30
4 dogs
5 100
6 squirrels
```