# Extracting information using Awk

Tags: string, awk

This post is related to my previous question about string splitting: [Awk split string into words and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66493061). Let's say we have a following string:

```
1A5T4
```

This string encodes the following information:
A at positon 2 (1 item before A)
T at position 8 (7 items before T , i.e. 1 + A + 5)
no more letters past the rightmost one mean no more relevant information to extract.

So the desired output here is `A T 2 8`

I'd like to write the Awk script to get this information, preferably in two arrays: one containing positions, the other containing letters. I thought this would be a convenient way to store it, as I need to use the values in other parts of the script that I am writing (or rather struggling to write).

I thought the first step would be to delimit the string by splitting it (credits go to helpful commenters [Awk split string into words and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66493061)).

```
echo 1A5T4 | awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]+/," & ")}1'
1 A 5 T 4
```

But maybe the delimiter is not necessary. I tried to do the task using a for loop, by iterating through consecutive letter-number pairs, and adding them to the arrays. However, I was not able to make it to work (there is no arrary, as I could not get the loop to work properly):

```
echo 1A5T4 | awk '{gsub(/[0-9]+$/,"", $0); a = $0}{for (i = 1; i <= length(a); i++2) {b = substr(a, i, 1) + 1 + b; print b}}'
        2
        3
        9
        10
```

*idea here was to get only numbers and then the letters in the separate for loop

I also had the idea of expanding the string like this: `.A.....T....` and then getting the positions of the letters by counting string lengths from the beginning until the letter.

The strings that I need to process will contain one more complication - another type of block: caret followed by a set of letters. In this block, the number of letters following a caret will be added to the final indices. Example below:

```
1A2^CCG3T4
```

A is 2 (as in the example above)
T is 11 (2 + 2 + 3 (sum of letter in CCG following the caret) + 3, so 10 positons that preceed T)

So the desired output here is `A T 2 11`

The letters following the caret are not relevant for anything else, except shifting the indices of the letter to the rate of the caret block.

Would be great to get some helpful hints on how to tackle this.

Clarification: the script should output all letters, as long as they are not preceded by caret. The letters after the caret only shift the indices. For example:

```
27T19T^A16G8G29
```

should give

```
 T T G G 28 48 66 75
```

and

```
27T19T16G8G29
```

should give

```
 T T G G 28 48 65 74
```

Update:

Thanks to @vgersh99, I managed to improve the code. It first converts the text blocks that follow each cater to the same format as the other blocks. Then all the blocks are dealt with in the same way (`for` loop), and in the end, caret values are just not displayed (the `if` statement). However, there is still the problem, in case there are multiple caret blocks of variable lengths.

```
1A5T4
1A1^AAAAA2T2
1A2^CCG3T4
27T19T^A16G8G29
27T19T16G8G29
1A^AA5^TT4T4
10A3A1G9A10A25^TT1^G1^G42T12^G1G29

{
  match($0, /\^[A-Z]+/);
  a = "^"length(substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH))-2"^";
  gsub(/\^[A-Z]+/, a)
}
# if a letter is directly followed by a caret, such carets are removed, as they would have count==0
{
  a = match($0, /[A-Z]+\^/);
  a = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH-1);
  gsub(/[A-Z]+\^/, a)
}
# intermediate string with transformed caret blocks is then used further
  {
      sum=0; delete(out); str=""
      n=patsplit($0,b, /[[:alpha:]^]/, seps);
      for(i=1; i<=n;i++) {
        sum+=seps[i-1]+1
        # print b[i], sum
        if (b[i]!="^")
        {out[sum]=b[i]}
      }

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for(i in out) {
      printf("%s ", out[i])
      str=(str? str OFS:"") i
  }

      print str
    } tst.txt

A T 2 8
A T 2 12
A T 2 12
T T G G 28 48 66 75
T T G G 28 48 65 74
A T 2 17
A A G A A T G 11 15 17 27 38 117 134
```

the last two values in the last row are incorrect, it should be 112 and 127.

This is because gsub always uses the first match to get the replacement for the string, and therefore all the replacements are identical in the intermediate string:

```
10A3A1G9A10A25^1^1^1^1^1^42T12^1^1G29
```

Comment: I'm quite confused with your changes - these reqs were not identified initially (at least the way I understand them now). I've made my own mods based on what you're doing, but I'm not getting the same results for the last sample you mentioned.
Pls create a separate chat discussion to discuss this further.

Comment: and Btw, the last line gets translated to ```10A3A1G9A10A25^1^1^G1^G42T12^G1G29``` after MY changes and before being processed. Is that the correct "translation"?

Comment: I think it's correct. I modified it slightly afterward to better fit my needs, and I consider this specific problem solved. The problem is very specific, and the tips I got here are enough to build upon. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated the "suggestion" with my latest code, with comments of what I think you're after and some of your "core" changes as well. The output it still not what you're after, but it' close - based on MY understand.
if you think it's good "enough" please mark it as a solution.
If not, let me know.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a rough approximation as I'm a bit confused about your explanation...
Will probably need to be tweaked a bit...
implemntation is `gawk` specific using gawk's support for `patsplit` and `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`.

Given `myFile.txt`:

```
1A5T4
1A1^AAAAA2T2
1A2^CCG3T4
27T19T^A16G8G29
27T19T16G8G29
1A^AA5^TT4T4
10A3A1G9A10A25^TT1^G1^G42T12^G1G29
```

```
$ cat tst.awk
# prep block for the following "core" mod block
{
   # if a caret is followed by letters, subsitute it by caret followed by the length of
   # the letter string (-1) followed by a caret
   # eg: 1A1^AAAAA2T2 -> 1A1^4^2T2
   #$0=gensub(/\^([[:alpha:]]+)/,"^" length("\\2")-2 "^","G")
   if(match($0,/\^([[:alpha:]]+)/,sub1))
           for (i=1;i in sub1;i++)
               sub(sub1[i],int(sub1[i,"length"])-1 "^")

   # if a letter is directly followed by a caret, such carets are removed, as they would have count==0
   $0=gensub(/([[:alpha:]])\^/,"\\1","G")
   #print "[" $0 "]"
   #next
}

# "core" mod block
# intermediate string with transformed caret blocks is then used further
{
      sum=0; delete(out); str=""
      n=patsplit($0,b, /[[:alpha:]^]/, seps);
      for(i=1; i<=n;i++) {
        sum+=seps[i-1]+1
        # print b[i], sum
        if (b[i]!="^")
        {out[sum]=b[i]}
      }

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for(i in out) {
      printf("%s ", out[i])
      str=(str? str OFS:"") i
  }
  print str
}
$ gawk -f tst.awk myFile.txt
A T 2 8
A T 2 12
A T 2 12
T T G G 28 48 66 75
T T G G 28 48 65 74
A T T T 2 11 12 17
A A G A A G G T G G 11 15 17 27 38 69 72 115 129 131
```

Comment: Thanks, I should be more clear indeed. I fixed the question, adding the desired output.

Comment: @LechKaczmarczyk, I don't see any "desired output" changes in the OP. Can you go with what's been provided and adjust as needed?

Comment: @LechKaczmarczyk, I've modified the code in case you only care about Ts or As

Comment: I wrote more clarification. But what you provided is perfectly fine to build upon! Thanks!

Comment: @LechKaczmarczyk, changed implemntation to using gawk's ```patsplit```. Looks like it creates the output in the wrong format though...

Comment: thanks a lot! I updated the question with improved code. There is still a problem with carets, maybe you have an idea how to do the replacement that I tried properly.

Comment: FYI: I posted a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66511714

Answer (score 1):

```
% echo 1A5T4 | gawk 'BEGIN{ FS=""; }{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if($i>="A"){ s=s $i } else { for(j=1;j<=$i;j++)s=s "." }} print s }'
.A.....T....
% echo 1A2^CCG3T4 | gawk 'BEGIN{ FS=""; }{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if($i>="A"){ s=s $i } else { for(j=1;j<=$i;j++)s=s "." }} print s }'
.A..^CCG...T....
%
```

maybe the caret handling is wrong, but that should not be too hard to fix...

Comment: Thanks! What's the purpose of s=s instances here?

Comment: It is not `s=s`, it is `s=s $i`  which concatenates `$i` to `s`. To see this in action you can do (on linux): `echo -e "1\n2\n3" | gawk '{ s=s $0; print s }'`

Comment: Thanks @Luuk for great clarification!

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this

```
{mawk/mawk2/gawk} 'BEGIN {  FS = "[=]+"; 
                           OFS =  "="; 
    } {
        outC = outP = pos = ""; 

        gsub(/\^/,          "=&" );   # first split carets next to letters
        gsub(/[0-9]+/,      "=&=");   # insert delims around numbers
         
    } { $1 = $1 } {

        while (match($0, /[\^][A-Z]+/)) { sub(/[\^][A-Z]+/, RLENGTH -1) } 
    } { 
        x = 1; do { 
             
           if ($(x) ~ /[0-9]+|^$/) { pos += int($(x)) } else { 

              outC = outC ""  $(x) " "; 
              outP = outP "" ++pos " "; 
      
        } } while (++x <= NF); print outC outP; } '
```

this version of the solution works in mawk and mawk2 as well. It doesn't require any sort of patsplit / FPAT logic, nor any gawk specific feature. It also doesn't even require a single call to substr( ).

It also avoids any of the hash-index overhead associated with dealing with arrays. Doesn't require any sorting either, since it's read sequentially left-to-right anyway.