# How to extract multiple strings with single regex expression in Awk

Tags: awk

I have the following strings:

```
Mike has XXX cats and XXXXX dogs.
MikehasXXXcatsandXXXXXdogs
```

I would like to replace Xs with the digits corresponding to the number of Xs:

I tried:

```
awk '{ match($0, /[X]+/);
  a = length(substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH));
  gsub(/[X]+/, a) }1'
```

But it captures only the first match.

Expected output:

```
Mike has 3 cats and 5 dogs.
Mikehas3catsand5dogs
```

Comment: Good point! `MikehasXXXcatsanXXXXXdogs` would be closer to what I need it for. But I was more interested in general approaches to the problem rather than the specifics.

Comment: @LechKaczmarczyk, ohhh since your samples are changed, so now we need to(me and karafka sir) need to change our approach too. It's a kind request to put samples like what Ed sir mentioned in very first place itself so no confusions later, cheers and happy learning

Answer (score 5):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`(should work in any `awk`).

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^X+$/){$i=gsub(/X/,"&",$i)}}} 1'  Input_file
```

Sample output will be:

```
Mike has 3 cats and 5 dogs.
```

***Explanation:*** Going through all the fields(space delimited) and checking if field starts from `X` and has only `X` till end of current field, if yes then globally substituting it with its own value(to get the count) and saving into current field itself. Then mentioning 1 will print current line.

---

---

***NOTE:*** As per Ed sir's comment(under question section), in case your fields may have values other `X` too then try(this will even cover `XXX456` value in any column too):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/X/){$i=gsub(/X/,"&",$i)}}} 1'  Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP's samples are changed so adding this solution here, written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='X+' '{ORS=(RT ? gsub(/./,"",RT) : "")} 1' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk -v RS='X+' '{ORS=(RT ? length(RT) : "")} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows for above code:

```
Mike has 3 cats and 5 dogs.
Mikehas3catsand5dogs
```

Comment: you can also use `length(RT)` instead of `gsub` for the last solution

Answer (score 3):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^X+$/) $i=length($i)}1' file

Mike has 3 cats and 5 dogs.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{while( match($0,/X+/) ) $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) RLENGTH substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} 1' file
Mike has 3 cats and 5 dogs.
Mikehas3catsand5dogs
```

Answer (score 1):

If Perl is okay:

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/X+/length $&/ge' ip.txt
Mike has 3 cats and 5 dogs.
Mikehas3catsand5dogs
```

The `e` flag allows Perl code in replacement section. `$&` will have the matched portion.

Comment: Would it be faster than awk? It's meant to be a step in a more complex text-processing pipeline, I thought wrapping everything in one Awk script will be more efficient.

Comment: Perl is usually slower than awk, but in this case it might be faster, can't be sure without profiling. If you already have other things in an awk script, I'd say stick with that solution instead of a combination of awk+perl.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the cleanest awk-based solution i can think of

```
 {mawk/mawk2/gawk} 'BEGIN { FS = "^$" } /X/ { 

      while(match($0, /[X]+/)) { sub(/[X]+/, RLENGTH) } } 1'
```

downside of this is having to use regex engine twice for every replacmeent. upside is that it avoids a bunch of `substr( )` ops.