# attempt to use array `s' in a scalar context

Tags: awk

I don't understand why this error pops up. I am trying to remove s, because otherwise, I get s appended recursively each iteration. It is only part of the whole code, but enough to reproduce the error.

```
echo M134K123G543 | awk '{
        
        delete(s)
        n = patsplit($0, b, /[^[:digit:]]/, seps);
        for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++) {
           for (j=1; j<=seps[i]; j++) {
               s=s b[i+1]
           }
       }
       print s
    }1'

awk: cmd. line:10: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use array `s' in a scalar context
```

Comment: because ```s``` is a string you're concatenating to: ```s=s b[i+1]```. And then you "think" it's an array you're trying to delete: ```delete(s)```.
If you want to delete with ```s``` as string, don't delete it as an array - simply "wipe it out" as a string: ```s=""```
Btw, if you want to have a private chat on your other thread(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66511714/how-to-extract-multiple-strings-with-single-regex-expression-in-awk), pls create one - I have updated code.

Comment: Thanks, `s=""` worked perfectly. And thanks for looking further into my other questions, it's a huge help!

Comment: please mark the appropriate answer as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `s` is a string you're concatenating to: `s=s b[i+1]`. And then you "think" it's an array you're trying to delete: `delete(s)`. If you want to delete with `s` as string, don't delete it as an array - simply "wipe it out" as a string: `s=""`

Comment: That doesn't delete s, it just sets its value to null. To delete it you'd set it to some non-existent variable. Try executing `awk 'BEGIN{s=7; s=""; if (s==0 && s=="") print "s is unset"}'` vs `awk 'BEGIN{s=7; s=x; if (s==0 && s=="") print "s is unset"}'`.